# Greek Font in Table of Contents

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, greek, times

I am using `Times` font for my main text via `newtxtext` package. I have both Greek and latin text. The problem is that in table of contents for Greek `Computer modern` font emerges now and then. This is what I get:

[image]

In the first line Greek Text (Logos-sarx) needs to be bold and not `Computer Modern` but some font that would fit good with Helvetica (which is used for the part of line "Ein in Fleisch gekleideter Gott").

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}%
\usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false]{geometry}
 \geometry{
   paperwidth=155mm,
   paperheight=230mm,
   inner=25mm,
       outer=23mm,
   bottom=20mm,
   top=27mm
}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{longtable}%
\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage{array}%
\usepackage{float}%
\usepackage{setspace}%
\usepackage{tabto}%
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{nameref}%
\usepackage{xpatch}%
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{rotating}%
\usepackage[textwidth=2cm, textsize=tiny, backgroundcolor=white, linecolor=black]{todonotes}%
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{newtxtext}% Times font
\usepackage{newtxmath}% if you need math
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \sbox0{\grk{A}%
  \global\expandafter\let
  \csname LGR/Tempora-TLF/m/sc\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname LGR/Tempora-TLF/m/n\endcsname
}}
\usepackage{textcomp}%
%
%
% TEXT
%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}% TEXT SPACING
%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
%
\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}}% GREEK TEXT
\newcommand{\lat}[1]{\emph{{#1}}}% LATIN TEXT
%
%
% BIBLATEX:%
%
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=false, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true, block=none]{biblatex}% change to hyperref=true to get clickable links
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}%
\bibliography{Inhalt}
%
%
%
% REDESIGNING TITLE STYLES (REQUIRES TITLESEC)
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% CHAPTER
  {\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\scshape\centering}
  {\scshape\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.\enskip}{1pt}{\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{30pt}% FIRST NUMBER BEFORE LAST NUMBER AFTER
\titleformat{\section}[block]% SECTION
  {\fontsize{10.5}{8}\selectfont\centering}
  {\thesection.\enskip}{1pt}{\fontsize{10.5}{8}\selectfont}
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{15pt}{15pt}% FIRST NUMBER BEFORE LAST NUMBER AFTER
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]% SUBSECTION
  {\fontsize{10.5}{8}\selectfont\centering\itshape}
  {\itshape\thesubsection.\enskip}{1pt}{\fontsize{10.5}{8}\selectfont}
  \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15pt}{10pt}% FIRST NUMBER BEFORE LAST NUMBER AFTER
%
%
\begin{document}%
%
%
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}%
\chapter{\grk{L'ogoc-s'arx} – Ein in Fleisch gekleideter Gott}\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{\grk{<Omoo'usios} – Der gottgleiche Sohn}
    \blindtext
    \begin{quote}\grk{o>uko~un t~w m`en >agenn'htw patr`i o>ike~ion >ax'iwma fulakt'eon, mhd'ena to~u e@inai a>ut~w t`on a>'ition l'egontas; t~w d`e u<i~w t`hn <arm'ozousan tim`hn >aponemht'eon, t`hn >'anarqon a>ut~w par`a to~u patr`os g'ennhsin >anatij'entas; ka`i <ws >efj'asamen a>ut~w s'ebas >apon'emontes, m'onon e>usebos ka`i e>uf'hmws t`o @hn ka`i t`o >ae`i ka`i t`o pr`o a>i'wnwn l'egontes >ep> a>uto~u, t`hn m'entoi je'othta a>uto~u m`h paraito'umenoi, >all`a t~h e>ik'oni ka`i t~w qarakt~hri to~u patr`os >aphkribwm'enhn >emf'ereian kat`a p'anta >anatij'entes, t`o d`e >ag'ennhton t~w patr`i m'onon >id'iwma pare~inai dox'azontes, <'ate d`h ka`i a>uto~u f'askontos to~u swt~hros; »<o pat'hr mou me'izwn mo'u >estin«.}\end{quote}
    \blindtext
    \cleardoublepage
    \end{document}%
```

Comment: Another typographic sin? If the title is in sans serif type, a serif Greek part is a punch in the eye.

Comment: No Greek text can be in Times here it doesn't have to be sans serif! Just not Computer modern! Sorry, but I have to have same font for Greek text all around.

Comment: You need then also `\substitutefont{LGR}{\sfdefault}{Tempora-TLF}`. And you should better implement the changes @egreg made to his answer in your last question. Also it doesn't make sense to load both newtxtext/newtxtmath and mathptmx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to substitute the `\sffamily` font with tempora too, you should add

```
\substitutefont{LGR}{\sfdefault}{Tempora-TLF}
```

[image]

(And I agree with egreg that it looks very bad. One wonder which publisher is requesting such a layout).

Comment: Publisher requested only that I remove `Computer modern` because it doesn't fit there and to make it bold. If you have better idea what font I should use there I am open to suggestions.

Comment: The rest of the title (Ein in Fleisch gekleideter Gott) is in Helvetica I think. Do you think the Greek part in Helvetica would look good? And how do I get it? :)

Comment: You could try `\substitutefont{LGR}{\sfdefault}{neohellenic}`.

Comment: I am no expert but that doesn't really look better to me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well I wouldn't use \sffamily here at all. There is no need to change both the weight and the shape. Also I normally use `\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrbook}`. But both in sans serif is nevertheless better than your current mix.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Best option name in history!

Comment: @egreg even better would have been `egregandulrikedontlikesansseriftitles`.

Comment: You know I actually believed there is this option and tried it :P. Maybe I am doing this in a wrong way: Tempora Greek part of the title in bold does not look nice but only because the rest of title is Helvetica. Maybe I should change all in Tempora? If you think that would look nice, how do I do this?

Comment: Remove all the titlesec code and use `\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrbook}`.

Comment: Omg so this is really an option name? I guess being involved in Latex development at so many levels has its perks :) Thank you both for help! Oh yes, and you asked about the publisher. It is one of the top 5 German publishing houses, so I guess you understand why I want to make this look good! They are useless with Latex though... not that I am much better...